# Openshot Video/Audio Preview has no Sound

Tags: openshot

Im trying to edit some videos in Openshot but there's no sound in the preview window. Sound works when I play the videos on VLC however.

The videos play with melt but they also have no sound. Im running Ubuntu 12.10. Spent a good two hours on Google searching for a solution with no results yet.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the video in 'tracks', go to properties, and make sure 'enable audio' is checked.

Audio (sound) has to be enabled on your track (ie: video) for you to be able to hear anything when you play your preview or download your video. When I first installed openshot I had the same problem as the OP- enabling audio solved it.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Well audio (sound) has to be enabled on your track (ie: video) for you to be able to hear anything when you play your preview or download your video. When I first installed openshot I had the same problem as the OP- enabling audio solved it.

Comment: If you could add that into your answer it would be the best ;).

Comment: There is no enable audio check box

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem on version 2.5.1, Worked for about 2 hours changing audio settings on pc and then matching those settings to OpenShot. Nothing helped.The solve for me was,in OpenShot go to Edit-Preferences,(Tab) Preview, Playback Audio Device (changed to DirectSound;Speakers.Found this trying each setting as 3 different settings seemed to be the same ,however only the one worked.

Comment: That option provides only one option "Default".  No drop down other than "Default".

Answer (score 1):

Openshot requires a video stream and an audio stream and you have to make sure that the eye and speaker icons are present and active to view and hear the video and that audio levels are normal...

Comment: Yeah volume is fine on VLC, and the eye and volume icons are showing. Videos preview fine, just without audio.

Comment: There is no eye and speaker icons

Answer (score 0):

Tryed  Edit-Preferences,(Tab) Preview, Playback Audio Device (changed to DirectSound;Speakers.  This did not work but did work if I chose speakers on attached monitor. When leaving as default or selecting DirectSound Speakers nothing else would play through those speakers when openshot was active. Its like open shot has had a go at using internal speakers and in process locks out other apps access.

Answer (score 0):

Check edit->Preferences->Preview->Playback Audio Device.

This was the issue for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1181728)

Answer (score 0):

Oddly my reputations are not high enough to comment, but I can post answers.  This will continue being a problem since Stackexhange hasn't been very interesting over several years, nor  helpful

Under windows 10, I do not have sound with Openshot video.  Using the suggested fixes does nothing.

Going to Edit>>preferences>>preview>>default playback audio device has 4 options
default
((my sound card)) and ((two virtual devices))

Default doesn't work, so trying the other three yields an error on program restart:
....."no such device"... which is it does not find my hardware which is present in all my other software except Opera browser, where I have a post in another thread that has been going for about 3 years now.

The other option is to right click the video track and select audio options, but there is no such options when I right click, perhaps because the audio isn't loading or detected since the software is blind to my having a sound card.

I will leave the software installed for a while, but not hopeful.   Was looking for a simple editing tool for some videos for work, not my favorite task.

:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scn55.jpg)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1243002)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found this question looking for answers. I was able to confirm with VLC that the video and audio were both recorded. None of the mentioned answers worked, but they helped me look in the right direction. **Edit-Preferences->Preview (tab)->Default Audio Sample Rate** was set to 44000, but my audio was recorded at 48000. After changing that, everything worked.

Comment: Changing to 48000 then demands that I restart OpenShot.  I do.  It's back to the prior value.  This even though I save the project and reopen the same project.

Comment: @JamesBowery sounds frustrating! You could try changing your digital input/output to 44000.